# Equivalent notation for the basis of L(V,W)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am getting myself confused as I have seen two definitions for the basis of L(V,W). Are both correct? And if so can someone help me see how they are equivalent?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the *same* bases. Just note that the $T_{kl}$ from the first definition is equal to the $T_{lk}$ of the second one.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this- it won’t let me accept an answer until 5 minutes but I will obviously accept it then. I need to stop assuming that every reference will use the same letters in a definition!